# bash check for subdirectories under directory

Tags: bash, shell

This is my first day scripting, I use linux but needed a script that I have been racking my brain until i finally ask for help. I need to check a directory that has directories already present to see if any new directories are added that are not expected.

---

Ok I think i have got this as simple as possible. The below works but displays all files in the directory as well. **I will keep working at it unless someone can tell me how not to list the files too** | I tried ls -d but it is doing the echo "nothing new". I feel like an idiot and should have got this sooner.

```
#!/bin/bash

workingdirs=`ls ~/ | grep -viE "temp1|temp2|temp3"`

if [ -d "$workingdirs" ]
then
echo "nothing new"

else

echo "The following Direcetories are now present"
echo ""
echo "$workingdirs"

fi
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: Use the find command.  Something like "find ~/ -type d | grep ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take some action when a new directory is created, used `inotifywait`.  If you just want to check to see that the directories that exist are the ones you expect, you could do something like:

```
trap 'rm -f $TMPDIR/manifest' 0

# Create the expected values.  Really, you should hand edit
# the manifest, but this is just for demonstration.
find "$Workingdir" -maxdepth 1 -type d > $TMPDIR/manifest

while true; do
    sleep 60 # Check every 60 seconds.  Modify period as needed, or
             # (recommended) use inotifywait
    if ! find "$Workingdir" -maxdepth 1 -type d | cmp - $TMPDIR/manifest; then
        : Unexpected directories exist or have been removed
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Below shell script will show directory present or not.

```
#!/bin/bash

Workingdir=/root/working/
knowndir1=/root/working/temp1
knowndir2=/root/working/temp2
knowndir3=/root/working/temp3
my=/home/learning/perl

arr=($Workingdir $knowndir1 $knowndir2 $knowndir3 $my) #creating an array

for i in ${arr[@]}     #checking for each element in array
do
        if [ -d $i ]
        then
        echo "directory $i present"
        else
        echo "directory $i not present"
        fi
done
```

output:

```
directory /root/working/ not present
directory /root/working/temp1 not present
directory /root/working/temp2 not present
directory /root/working/temp3 not present
**directory /home/learning/perl present**
```

Comment: I dont need to know if the expected dirs are present just the ones that show up that are not expected. So say i have temm1 temp2 and temp 3 that I know are there. If say unknowndir1 shows up i need to know that its there. Thats it. I am trying to make as simple as possible lol, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This will save the available directories in a list to a file.  When you run the script a second time, it will report directories that have been deleted or added.

```
#!/bin/sh

dirlist="$HOME/dirlist"  # dir list file for saving state between runs
topdir='/some/path'      # the directory you want to keep track of

tmpfile=$(mktemp)

find "$topdir" -type d -print | sort -o "$tmpfile"

if [ -f "$dirlist" ] && ! cmp -s "$dirlist" "$tmpfile"; then
    echo 'Directories added:'
    comm -1 -3 "$dirlist" "$tmpfile"

    echo 'Directories removed:'
    comm -2 -3 "$dirlist" "$tmpfile"
else
    echo 'No changes'
fi

mv "$tmpfile" "$dirlist"
```

The script will have problems with directories that have very exotic names (containing newlines).